# Query on Params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to get records based on params received. Sometimes I receive 2 params or sometimes 3. I have written a code to get results when all 3 params received but when I receive only 1 param am getting 0 results.

Example

```
Office.where(state: params[:state], type: params[:type]).where("name like ?","%#{params[:name]}%")
```

When i get values like

```
{state: "KA", type: "private", name: "google"}
```

But when I get the only {name: "google"} I get no records

I have tried with condition

```
If params[:name].present? && params[:state].present? && params[:type].present?
query
elsif condition
query
end
```

Let me know how can I solve this or any better way

Comment: What Rails version are you using?

Comment: rails 5.2.2 and ruby 2.5.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a parameter is missing, it will probably be blank. If you pass them all in this will result in clauses like `type = ''`. For example, if only `name` is passed in you'll get something like...

```
where name like '%google%' and type = '' and state = ''
```

You need to strip out the blank fields. There are various ways to do this. Since you have a special case, the `name` clause, one good way to handle this is to build the query piece by piece.

```
query = Office.all
query = query.where(state: params[:state]) if params[:state].present?
query = query.where(type: params[:type]) if params[:type].present?
query = query.where("name like ?","%#{params[:name]}%") if params[:name].present?
```

The query does not execute until you fetch the values from `query`.

If there's a lot of simple parameters you can make a Hash and remove the pairs with a blank value.

```
qparams = {
  state: params[:state],
  type: params[:type]
}.select { |k,v|
  v.present?
}

query = Office.where(qparams)
query = query.where("name like ?","%#{params[:name]}%") if params[:name].present?
```

Or use the handy [compact_blank gem](https://github.com/sue445/compact_blank).

```
using CompactBlank

qparams = {
  state: params[:state],
  type: params[:type]
}.compact_blank

query = Office.where(qparams)
query = query.where("name like ?","%#{params[:name]}%") if params[:name].present?
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this

In controller

```
filter_params = params.slice(:state, :type, :name)
Office.filter(filter_params)
```

In `Office` model

```
scope :state, -> (state) { where(state: state) }
scope :type, -> (type) { where(type: type) }
scope :name, -> (name) { where("name LIKE ?", "%#{name}%") }

def self.filter(filter_params)
  results = where(nil)
  filter_params.each do |key, value|
    results = results.public_send(key, value) if value.present?
  end
  results
end
```

**PS: It runs a single query irrespective of the number of params!**

Hope that helps!

Comment: You're gonna do three queries or `n` depending on the number of needed and present params. There should be probably something simpler.

Comment: @SebastianPalma No it doesn't, it will run a single query. That's the beauty of ActiveRecord in Rails!

Comment: @Schwern It didn't, had to define scopes. But now it should work!

Comment: @RajdeepSingh I like the use of scopes. Using `public_send` raises security issues, if they're not using strong params any public method can potentially be called. I wonder if it's better to make the scopes ignore blanks. `scope :state, -> (state) { where(state: state) if state.present? }` etc... then `Office.state(state).type(type).name(name)`

Comment: @Schwern What security issues you are talking about? The params are already filtered for the required parameters using `slice` in controller. And blanks are already handled inside the `filter` method.

Comment: @RajdeepSingh A malicious attacker can potentially call any public method on the Relation. For example, `yourapp?delete=42`. One can argue sanitizing the parameters is the Controller's job, but anyone can call `Office.filter` without realizing the risk. Layered security is best. If the scopes handle blanks there's no need for a special filter method and a bunch of code goes away, though I've been bitten by putting too much logic into scopes.

Comment: @RajdeepSingh They will be filtered this time, but `Office.filter` is a public method. What if six months later someone else uses `Office.filter`, doesn't realize the risk, and isn't so careful with their params? Security works best if people don't have to be careful.

Comment: @Schwern How can a hacker call a model method without going through the controller? In this case, we need to filter three params, in another method we might need to filter other set of params. I guess it's better to handle it in the controller side to filter the params. Although I agree that in model side OP should restrict filter to table columns only.